# Html don't go to A href location when clicked on another element above it

Tags: html, css, href

I was wondering if its possible to prevent my `div` from going to the href in my `A` tag when pressed. My div is current floating over my `A` tag with `position: absolute`.

Jsfiddle with my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ac80u7bd/

I need the css style: `position: relative` in my `div` to prevent my button from sticking to the top left of the page. I'm not sure if this is causing the problem.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="image col-md-6">
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img width="500" height="300" src="http://i.imgur.com/uR2o8pb.jpg">
  </a>
  <div class="edit-image">&middot;&middot;&middot;</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.image {
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

.image .edit-image{
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Is it possible to not follow the href when clicking on the `<div class="edit-image">` element?

Comment: Not related to the issue, but there is a typo here: `width-"500"` should be `width="500"`

Comment: @domdom solved it thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `pointer-events:none;` and voila!

```css
.image {
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.image .edit-image {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="image col-md-6">
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img width="500" height="300" src="http://i.imgur.com/uR2o8pb.jpg">
  </a>
  <div class="edit-image">&middot;&middot;&middot;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was fiddling with the fiddle for the longest time and I never would've tried that. Good catch! PS: there is a button in the editor to insert a JS fiddle. Might want to use that.

Comment: im glad i helped you :) best of luck!

Comment: Yes thats it! :-) I added that before because I had the button first in the A tag. I removed it after and forgot to remove the `pointer-events:none;` thanks!

Comment: @domdom oh now i notice :D im new to stackoverflow, been a long time lurker, now that i have learned some stuff, ill try to help people :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want.

```css
.image {
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.image .edit-image{
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="image col-md-6">
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img width-"500" height="300" src="http://i.imgur.com/uR2o8pb.jpg">
  </a>
  <div class="edit-image">&middot;&middot;&middot;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now you can't click the red square, but neither can you click the image itself.

Comment: Yeah I was looking for a way to not being able to click just the red square/button.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want the image clickable but not the red square.